# Launching applications from application launcher with "TZ=UTC" prefixed stopped working

Tags: arch-linux, mate-desktop, troubleshooting, launcher

I had a launcher for firefox with command `TZ=UTC firefox`. Suddenly it stopped working, I think after I did `pacman -Syu` (I only clicked again much later so it could be something else). I am using arch linux and mate.

I also tested trying to open other applications with `TZ=UTC` prefixed and it didn't work, so doesn't seem like a firefox issue.

When I click the launcher nothing happens. If I type the command of the launcher in the terminal it works. How can I further investigate what's happening / fix this?

Comment: What happens if you replace `TZ=UTC` with `env TZ=UTC`?

Comment: @Bob that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `TZ=UTC` with `env TZ=UTC`. TZ=UTC is bash (POSIX shell) syntax. env, on another hand, is a program in itself. This is why when you run the command in terminal it works. You can find more info in [the env manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/env.1.html).